# City field validation not working

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.6

Tried via checkout_index_index.xml to add validation on city field in 2.2.6 still now working

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">                                                                    
   <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">                                        
   <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>                               
   </item>
</item>
```

Comment: In Default Magento, city validation field is working, what's your issue?

Comment: We are using onestepcheckout where city validation is not working when we try with above XML

Comment: have you tried adding `class="required-entry"` in phtml ?

Comment: Facing this issue with one-step checkout which is been generated by JS and XML